# jQuery autocomplete not filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a jQuery autocomplete control that is populating with data but the list just displays when I type anything in the box and doesn't filter my results.  Does anyone know how to alter this behavior?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('#datePicker').datepicker();
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "FacilitiesAsync",
                type: 'GET',
                cache: true,
                data: 'sourceDb=myDb',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (json) {
                    response($.map(json, function (name) {
                        return {
                            label: name.label,
                            value: name.value
                        };
                    }));
                },
                error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#autocomplete").text(textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#autocomplete').val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function () {
            }
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Your JS isn't sending the text inside the input. The server-side needs that to know what to filter by.

Comment: So how would you recommend doing that Eduard?

Comment: I have the list from the server.  I don't want to pass back to the server an additional request to get a filtered result set, INSTEAD, I want to filter the list that I already have, make sense?